# service crashes while in loop - Android Studio

Tags: android

i'm basicaly tying to open up a service, that every 10 seconds, will show up a toast to say "10 seconds passed"
this is what i'm trying to do, 
and after many research ive found out that to loop a service i'm 
going to need to use while (true) - sleep... method... 
but the service or my app crashes every time i start the service 
(or to be exact every time the timer runs out)

what is my problem ?

my guess is that maybe the contaxt i'm passing to the toast is wrong ? 
maybe there is another way to show toast every 10 seconds in loop (inside a serivice) ?

here is my service code >

```
package com.greenroad.candidate.mywallpaperchanger;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by pitsponet on 31/08/2015.
 */
public class myService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service created",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //try to run loop for showing up a toast
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //REST OF CODE HERE//
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service started",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }).start();


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service stoped",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: If it crashes you should be able to get a stack trace. Try posting that as it will provide much more detail as to what's going on.

Comment: hey Acapulco, unfortuntly i can't stack trace it becouse i'm building this as an APK file and uploading it to my device, currently Android Studio doesn't see my device, and also the simulator in it doesn't work so i can't check it in any other way.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it's clear to you now.

Comment: yes now it is much clearer thnx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the crash, as explained by Brad, is because you are trying to perform UI operation from a non-UI `Thread`.

To achieve what you're trying to do, use the code below in your service. First of all remove your `Thread` in `onStartCommand()`

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(ToastTask, 10000); // Starts the loop here
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop the loop
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(ToastTask);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    private Runnable ToastTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "10 Seconds have passed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Schedule this Runnable to run again after 10 sec
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is correct as he is creating a new thread for the infinite while loop in the onStartCommand() method.

Comment: @Bradford2000 Oh sorry. I see that now. My solution would work though. I think it's the same as yours, though mine seems more complete.

Comment: tried adding it to my onStartCommand but it didn't work, since it outputs allot of errors, where do you add this ? and how you call this loop ?

Comment: @ShayVidas Add it inside your service. The code in my answer is looping. It will show Toast every 10 seconds.

Comment: david since,  Acapulco has gave me a -1 point i can't ask another question, but my first question was only stage one of this service, in the end i want to change the wallpaper of my phone every 10 minuts... i can't ask this question now since i'm on freeze for 3 days.. but maybe you know how i can do this from outside my main activicty ?

Comment: @ShayVidas To change wallpaper `try { WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setResource(R.drawable.my_wallpaper); } catch(IOException e){}` Please accept answer if it helped.

Comment: @ShayVidas Oh I forgot to mention that you need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to be able to change wallpaper.

Comment: hey David, your awsome, wish there would be more people like you ...amm i didn't tested it yet, but will this work OUTSIDE my main activity ? becouse i'm calling it from inside a service, or from inside a diffrent class,  also how will i make it strach to full screen ? and not zoom in like it will in default ? (again from OUTSIDE my activity .. tha'ts the main problem..)

Comment: @ShayVidas It will work inside the Service. As for the wallpaper stretching, you'll have to resize and crop to proper size before settig the wallpaper. Please post another question if you have trouble making it work. And please mark this answer as correct if it has answered your original question.

Comment: @ShayVidas Haha okay Shay. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the service is crashing is because you're trying to run UI tasks (Toasts) outside of the main thread. Since you are creating a secondary thread for the infinite while loop, you'll need to post your Toast calls to the main looper as follows:

```
final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

That being said, I highly discourage using Thread.sleep() in any code that will run on a device, as this could lead to some serious issues. You should be able to accomplish the same thing (and also get rid of the infinite while-loop) using a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) instead.

To use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), you should be able to do something like the following:

```
// Schedules a TimerTask to execute every 10 seconds after a 10 second delay.
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your Toast code here.
    }
}, 10000, 10000);
```

Here's a complete example:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Handler mainHandler;
    private Timer timer;

    public void onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        mainHandler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 10000, 10000);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        timer.cancel();
    }

    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()  {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great, that does show the toast, but how do i loop it ? do you have a code example of the timer i'll need to put in ? tried to look for it in vain

Comment: Edited to include the Timer example. Also, the answer that @DavidH posted above is functionally equivalent, just using Handler instead of Timer for the looping.